# Calculating probabilities in a children's card game

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

So I want to know how to calculate the probabilities of opening a specfic hand in a 44 card deck in which you draw 5 cards in you 1st turn. Lets say I have 3 copies of Stratos, 3 copies of Faris, 3 copies of A Hero Lives, 2 copies of Mali and 33 blank cards, I want to know the chances of opening Stratos+Faris, Stratos+A Hero Lives, Stratos+Mali, Faris+A Hero Lives, Faris+Mali OR Mali+A Hero Lives

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Lets say I have a 44 card deck, and I want to draw various 2 card specific hand. In this deck I have 3 copies of a card called Stratos, 3 copies of Faris, 3 copies of A Hero Lives and 2 copies of Mali, for the sake of the argument we can say the remaining 33 cards are blank. I want to know my chances of opening in my 1st 5 card hand any of the following: Stratos+Faris, Stratos+A Hero Lives, Stratos+Mali, Faris+A Hero Lives, Faris+Mali OR Mali+A Hero Lives

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the plus sign?

Comment: Opening both card, lets say in the 1st 5 card hand I have a Stratos, a Mali and 3 blank cards

Comment: What do you mean by  "opening both card ...  in the 1st 5 card hand I have"

Comment: You have a deck of 44 cards, in the 1st turn you draw 5 cards.

Comment: If your cards are Stratos+Stratos+Faris+Mali+Blank, is it a win, or a loose ? Same for all similar combinations. If it is a loose, the answer is 22.6%, as detailed by JKumley ; if it is a win, the probability raises to 31.5%

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{245520\text{ desired combinations}}{1086008\text{ total combinations}} \approx 22.6\text{%}$

Why?

1. There are $44 \times 43 \times 42 \times 41 \times 40$ ways to deal 5 cards from a set of 44, when order matters (permutations).
2. There are $5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1$ ways to order 5 cards.
3. $1,2 \implies$ There are $\frac{44 \times 43 \times 42 \times 41 \times 40}{5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1} = 1086008$ ways to deal 5 cards from a set of 44, when order does not matter (combinations).
4. There are $3$ ways to deal 1 card from a set of 3.
5. $4 \implies$ There are $3 \times 3$ ways to deal 1 card from 3 sets of 3.
6. $5 \implies$ There are $(3 \times 3) \times (2 \times 3)$ ways to deal 1 card from 3 sets of 3 and 1 card from 2 sets of 3, when order matters (permutations).
7. There are $2 \times 1$ ways to order 2 cards.
8. $6,7 \implies$ There are $\frac{(3 \times 3) \times (2 \times 3)}{2 \times 1}$ ways to deal 1 card from 3 sets of 3 and 1 card from 2 sets of 3, when order does not matter (combinations).
9. There are $2$ ways to deal 1 card from a set of 2.
10. $4,9 \implies$ There are $(3 \times 3) \times (1 \times 2)$ ways to deal 1 card from 3 sets of 3 and 1 card from 1 set of 2.
11. $6,10 \implies$ There are $\frac{(3 \times 3) \times (2 \times 3)}{2 \times 1} + (3 \times 3) \times (1 \times 2) = (3 \times 3) \times (3 + 2)$ ways to deal 1 card from 3 sets of 3 and 1 card from either a set of 3 or a set of 2.
12. There are $33 \times 32 \times 31$ ways to deal 3 cards from a set of 33, when order matters (permutations).
13. There are $3 \times 2 \times 1$ ways to order 3 cards.
14. $12,13 \implies$ There are $\frac{33 \times 32 \times 31}{3 \times 2 \times 1}$ ways to deal 3 cards from a set of 33, when order does not matter (combinations).
15. $11,14 \implies$ There are $\frac{33 \times 32\times 31 \times (3 \times 3) \times (3 + 2)}{3 \times 2 \times 1} = 245520$ ways to deal 3 cards from a set of 33, 1 card from a set of 3, and 1 card from either a set of 3 or a set of 2, when order does not matter (combinations).
16. $3,15 \implies$ There is a $\frac{245520}{1086008} \approx 22.6\text{%}$ chance that the desired combinations will be drawn.

Comment: A phenomenal 16-step counting process! Well done!

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer by Jeffrey Kumley assumes that the hand should include *only* those two special cards, and the remaining cards must be blank. Another possible interpretation of the question is (as discussed in the comments) that the hand should include *at least* those two special cards, and the remaining cards can be any cards. Here’s a solution for this latter interpretation.

So we want to calculate the probability to draw at least two types out of the four types Stratos, Faris, A Hero Lives and Mali. Often it’s easier to calculate the probability of the complementary event, in this case, drawing either none or only one of those types.

The number of hands that include at most a particular one of those four types that has $k$ copies is $\binom{44-11+k}5$. We need to add this for the four types, but then we’ve counted the hands with none of the four types four times, so we need to subtract them $3$ times. There are $\binom{44-11}5$ such hands. Thus there are

$$
\binom{44-11+2}5+3\binom{44-11+3}5-3\binom{44-11}5=648024
$$

hands that contain at most one of those four types, so the probability to draw at least two of the types is

$$
1-\frac{648024}{\binom{44}5}=\frac{3891}{12341}\approx32\%\;.
$$